# How to use fetchrow_arrayref correctly in perl script?

Tags: perl, dbi

I got stuck in the usage of 'fetchrow_arrayref' in Perl script. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong in the script? I'd appreciate whatever you could inform me. Thank you.

The problems I'm facing are:

(1) print $id; <-this doesn't print the content of $id.

(2) print "$list[1]"; <-this prints ARRAY(0x8da6978) instead of the actual content.

(3) reverse(@list); <-this doesn't reverse the contents of @list.

(4) print "@{$_} \n";  <- "\n" doesn't work. Also why do we need @{}?

(5) print "\n";  <-this doesn't work as well.

(6) print "@list";  <-this prints ARRAY(0x8da6978).

(7) print Dumper(@inverse);  <-prints fine, but the contents of the array is not reversed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

....

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword) || die "Error $DBI::errstr";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM name WHERE id = 11");
$sth->execute;

my @list = ();

while(my $element = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref){

    push(@list, $element);

}


$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;

my ($id, $name, $email, $telephone) = @list;

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";

print $id;                                           (problem 1)

print "$list[1]";                                    (problem 2)

my @inverse = reverse(@list);                        (problem 3)

foreach (@inverse){

    print "@{$_} \n";                                (problem 4)

}

print "\n";                                          (problem 5)

print "@list";                                       (problem 6)

print Dumper(@inverse);                              (problem 7)

exit;
```

Comment: You should understand what reference means..`$list[1]` prints `ARRAY(0x8da6978)` which is reference try `$list->[1]`. try to understand how to deference array.

Comment: if you provide the dumper values then anybody can help you in this forum..

Comment: The dumper values of the above script is:  ARRAY(0x9e387a0)11 Name sample@email.com 03-5725-8830 ARRAY(0x9e387a0)$VAR1 = [ '11', 'Name', 'sample@email.com', '03-5725-8830'];   print "/n" doesn't work at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your note. I've tried $list->[1], but it still doesn't work...

Comment: `$list->[1]->{'name'}`

Answer (score 2):

Each item in your list will be a reference to an array containing the data for one row of your database table.

This:

```
my ($id, $name, $email, $telephone) = @list;
```

appears to be trying to process one row of the table.

You need to do that for *each member* of `@list` and not `@list` itself.

```
for my $row (@list) {
    my ($id, $name, $email, $telephone) = @$row;
    print $id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I've tried the code you suggested, but it still doesn't print anything on the screen...

Answer (score 1):

$sth->fetchrow_arrayref will return the arrayref and you push that on @list. Now the @list array contain the arrayref on every index and the reference will the same.
Therefore, you should push the value of array in @list like:
push(@list, @$element);